# Ubuntu 12.04 beta install ROS desktop full

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
I am new with ROS and I came upon such a problem: when I try to install ROS desktop full I get:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
...

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-electric-desktop-full : Depends: ros-electric-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.5-s1331966280~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-vision-opencv (= 1.6.11-s1331999864~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-perception-pcl (= 1.0.2-s1331960978~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-pipeline (= 1.6.4-s1332000899~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-simulator-gazebo (= 1.4.12-s1331968141~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.2-s1332000717~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-navigation (= 1.6.5-s1331963038~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I then manually try to install missing dependencies I end up with 2 packages:
libtiff4-dev and libjpeg62-dev which delete one another when installed. So if I try to install one it automatically removes another.

I understand that this problem related on my using beta distribution, but maybe someone already faced this thing and knows how to deal with it?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30234/ubuntu-12.04-beta-install-ros-desktop-full/) by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You still have oneiric (=11.10) packages in your sources.list and you try to install them on a 12.04 system. This is doomed to fail. You should clean up the sources.list for 12.04 ("pangolin"). However, as per http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html there are no electric ROS packages for 12.04. In fact, I don't think 12.04 is even in the build system yet.

So you would need to try a source-based install instead.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2012-03-22**:
Yeah, I tried that as a last hope - it helps sometimes with smaller packages - just to include ones from previous versions. :) I know that it's stupid, but sometimes works.
When I try to build from sources I get in the end an error message:
Failed to find rosdep boost for package rosparam on precise

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Electric will not be targeted for 12.04 [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#electric-emys-aug-2011)

ROS Fuerte will be ported to run on 12.04 once we get the Fuerte release stabilized on the other platforms.

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4